# XPath: Get element with matching attribute value

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to get content from an element whose @id attribute matches the context node's @idref. For example, given the following xml (just a contrived sample)...

```
<doc>
   <toc>
      <entry idref="ch1"/>
      <entry idref="ch2"/>
   </toc>
   <body>
      <chapter id="ch1">
         <title>Chapter 1</title>
         <para/>
      </chapter>
      <chapter id="ch2">
         <title>Chapter 2</title>
         <para/>
      </chapter>
      <chapter id="ch3">
         <title>Chapter 3</title>
         <para/>
      </chapter>
   </body>
</doc>
```

From the [entry] element, how can I get the content of [title] within [chapter] whose @id matches the current @idref.

So, basically find chapter[where chapter @id = current entry @idref]/title

I've tried

```
string(//chapter[@id = @idref]/title)
string(//chapter[@id = ./@idref]/title)
string(//chapter[@id = current()/@idref]/title)
```

all with no luck.

Comment: Are you looking for any `chapter` with an `@id` that is equal to the `@idref` of any `entry`, or does there have to be some kind of relationship  between `chapter` and `entry`?

Comment: No relationship needed. Just looking for any chapter which has an `@id` that is equal to the `@idref` of the entry. I know there will only be one chapter with a matching `@id`.

Comment: Actually, in your xml there are two matching chapters - 1 and 2.

Comment: not sure how there are two matching chapters? Each chapter has a unique id, so <entry idref="ch1"/> should match the first chapter and <entry idref="ch2"/> should match the second chapter (based on the chapter `@id` value.

Comment: Exactly - that's what I meant by two chapters, each of each has a match with one entry. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. Each `<entry>` will match a `<chapter>`. I'm having trouble finding out the title of the chapter it matches. So, if the context node is `entry`, how do I find the title of the matching chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this expression on your xml?

```
//chapter[@id=//toc/entry/@idref]/string-join((title,@id),' ')
```

Output:

```
Chapter 1 ch1
Chapter 2 ch2
```

Comment: That doesn't do it. That will just grab the first entry that has an `@idref' that matches a chapter `@id`.
For example, `<entry idref="ch1"/>` and `<entry idref="ch2"/>` will both output the title for chapter 1

Comment: @user3198443 - Interesting; based on the xml in the question, I get the output I just pasted in the answer. See [this, for example](http://xpather.com/lbnVLF2C).

Comment: This xpath returns two elements, but all it's doing is checking for any chapters that have a matching `@id/@idref` with entry. It's not using a specific `@idref` to match a specific chapter `@id`. Imagine the context node is the second `<entry/>`, and FROM that entry we are trying to get the matching chapter title. Surely that xpath statement must contain the current `@idref`? Something like
`string(//chapter[@id = ./@idref]/title)`
which doesn't work, but indicates that we are looking for a chapter that has an `@id` that matches current `@idref` (or ch2 in this case)

Comment: @user3198443 - I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. If you can come up with another xml snippet where this xpath expression provides the _wrong_ output, it may clarify things.

Comment: If you change the order of the entry element, so you have
`      <entry idref="ch2"/>
      <entry idref="ch1"/>`
you still get the same result, chapter 1 first and chapter 2 second. This is because it's getting any chapters that have an `@id` that matches an `@idref`. It's not actually checking from ENTRY for a matching chapter.

Comment: @user3198443 - I believe I actually understand what you're trying to do! See edit above.